# Is auto_now_add property updated each time when put is called?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have db model, where one property has `auto_now_add=True`. But looks like it doesn't work as I've expected - it is updated each time when `put` is called (I use my own `key_name`, so second/third/N call of `put` doesn't really create new record - just update it).

Here is the code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.IntegerProperty()
    added = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    name = db.StringProperty()

...
    # this handler can be called several times
    def get(self):
        user = User(key_name="id"+unique_user_id)
        user.id = unique_user_id
        user.name = current_name
        user.put()
```

Comment: @ShayErlichmen, I've added the code. `unique_user_id`, `current_name` - is what I get from another (3rd party) site. `current_name` can be changed, so I need to re-read it sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are recreating the entity each time, here is how the code should look like:

```
#This will create the object only once
return User.get_or_insert(key_name="id%d" % unique_user_id, 
                          id=unique_user_id, 
                          name = current_name)

#This will create the object and update some properties
#You can't change the value of key_name
user = User.get_or_insert(key_name="id%d" % unique_user_id, 
                          id=unique_user_id)
user.name = name
user.put()
return user
```

Comment: But it will not update the record, if it is already there, right? I need to have that updated.

Answer (score 1):

By overwriting the entity each time, you are effectively creating a new record. The distinction between `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` is enforced by the model framework; it has no way of acting differently based on whether the record already exists or not. Instead, you should update the existing record as [@Shay suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784486/31671).

Comment: btw @Nick the datastore needs to have update_or_insert() : model  so the above code will only commit once (and in a single tx)

Comment: @ShayErlichmen `get_or_insert` is simply a convenience method; it doesn't do anything you couldn't do yourself with a transaction. Likewise for an `update_or_insert` function.

Comment: I know, but still it will be very convenient to have one out of the box.

Comment: @ShayErlichmen Honestly, I wish `get_or_insert` didn't exist, because it leads to people writing solutions that needlessly do additional writes like your answer, when they could do it all in a single transaction.